# Ebleco, eblo aŭ eblaĵo?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Kio estas la ĝusta vorto por esprimi ke ia situacio povas okazi en la estonteco? Mi jam aŭdis ĉiun version, do *ebleco*, *eblo* kaj *eblaĵo*. Sed kio estas la ĝusta?

Cetere, kio estas la diferenco en la signifo de tiuj tri vortoj?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ni diskutis tiun demandon dum NASK ĉi-jare. Mi konvinkiĝis pro la klarigo de Bertilo Wennergren ke la ĝusta vorto plej ofte estas "eblo", dum multege da esperantistoj, pro nacilingva influo, tro uzas "ebleco".

"Eblo" kovras la signifojn kaj de "ebleco" kaj de "eblaĵo".

- eblaĵo - io kio povos okazi.
- ebleco - la eco de esti ebla.

Sekve:

- Estas tri ebloj (aŭ eblaĵoj), A, B, kaj C.
- La ebleco (aŭ eblo) de mia baldaŭa morto malgajigas min.

Answer (score 6):

Mi ne scias pri la vorto eblaĵo.

> Ebleco = La eco esti ebla: ebleco de tia evoluo estas tre malgranda;
>   ni lasos por kelka tempo flanke la demandon pri la ebleco aŭ neebleco
>   de la enkonduko de lingvo internacia [5].
>
> Eblo = Io kio povas okazi, io kion oni povas profiti: ŝajnas, ke
>   respondi tiun ĉi demandon ekzistas nenia eblo [6]; mi ne havas la
>   eblon forveturi; la sufiksoj donas la eblon el unu vorto fari aliajn
>   vortojn; lingvo neŭtrale homa, kiu ... donus al la homoj de malsamaj
>   nacioj la eblon kompreniĝadi inter si [7]; alia eblo estas ke la angla
>   aŭ iu varianto aŭ piĝina ĵargono de ĝi ja farigos la internacia
>   komunikilo [8]; deverbaj substantivoj ofte povas montri egale aŭ la
>   agon aŭ rezulton de la ago ... la du lastaj ekzemploj ... ilustras la
>   unuan eblon [9].

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/ebl.html#ebl.0a